# IIS 7.5 Not Working with Remote (External) IP

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I just installed IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 Ultimate from Control Panel with Default Settings and Everything is going fine when I access the site with "localhost" or my local Ip "192.168.0.2"

But when I access from my external IP which I got from http://www.whatismyip.com/ it is not working.

**Its giving me error:**

> Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 117.199.144.242:82

where 82 is my port for the site.

And when I am accessing the IP without port it is taking me to Netgear Login Page because I am using Netgear Router.

So Please Help me in Solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your PCs IP is 192.168.0.2
2. Your "external IP" 117.x.x.x is your Netgear router (not your PC)

The above should explain why.

- You'll have to configure port forwarding in your Netgear
- You will only be able to use your "external ip" from an "external location" (outside your home network).
- You will need to use your **internal IP (192.x.x.x)** from a machine inside your home network (they will both have a 192.x.x.x address).

Answer (score 0):

You need to forward external port 80 (or 82) to your internal (192.168.x.y) IP and port (80 or 82).

You have instructions [here](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Netgear/default.htm) (find your router if it's in the list).